# How do I find the set $\bigcup_{k = 2}^{10}A_k$ if $A_k = [k, 2k-1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I find $\bigcup_{k = 2}^{10}A_k$ knowing that $A_k = [k, 2k-1]$?
I thought about writing each set and then drawing the line segments on X axis, what is the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You can write down all the sets separately and that will work, but there is a quicker way to do this.

For first intuition, note that $A_{2}=[2,3]$, $A_{3}=[3,5]$ and $A_{4}=[4,7]$. So we see that in fact, if $k\geq 2$ then $$2k-1= k+k-1\geq k+2-1=k+1.$$ So the larger endpoint of $A_{k}$ is greater than the lower endpoint of $A_{k+1}$. So the intervals $A_{k}$ and $A_{k+1}$ always overlap. Can you see from here how to conclude what $\bigcup_{k=2}^{10}A_{k}$ should be?

Comment: Is it [2, 19]??

Comment: @LiziPizi: Yes, that’s correct.